# Error connecting to SQL with VB

Tags: mysql, vb.net, wamp

So i tried to connect my sql database to my vb project but it gives me this error:

> Error Connecting to Database : Authentication to host "for user" using
>   method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message : Acces denied for
>   user "@'N56VB' (using password : NO)

N56VB is my pc

UPDATE the error wich I get now is : A first chance exception of type

> 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Keyword not supported.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely
>   continued

I dont know what to do anymore it will be a stupid I guess ,be easy on me i'm a noob :( 
I hope someone knows the problem

```
  Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Public Class NieuweItems
    Public dbconn As New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;user id=root;password=;database=gip;")
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
    Private Sub btn_return_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_return.Click
        Me.Close()
        SalesApplication.Show()
    End Sub
    Private Sub btn_inlezen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_inlezen.Click
        Dim sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand
        Dim SQLConnection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection
        Dim strStockSQL As String
        SQLConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source= localhost ;user id = root'@'localhost; password = ;database=gip;table=stock;"
        Try
            conn.Open()
            strStockSQL = "INSERT INTO Barcode " & txtBarcode.Text & "INSERT INTO Naam_Product" & txtNaam.Text & "INSERT INTO Verkoopprijs" & txtVP.Text
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            SQLConnection.Close()
            conn.Close()
        Catch myerror As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show("Error Connecting to Database: " & myerror.Message)
        Finally
            conn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/

Answer (score 0):

I presume that the error is occurring inside the "btn_inlezen_Click" event handler? I think what's happening is that you're declaring a new empty MySqlConnection, opening the connection inside your Try block and only then are you setting the ConnectionString. Because MySqlConnection was declared with no parameters it might be trying to use N56VB as the user account and this doesn't have any permissions on your MySQL db.

So set your connection string before opening the connection.

Comment: I tried and now I get this : An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Keyword not supported.

Comment: Something wrong in your connection string then; visit http://www.connectionstrings.com/ and make sure your string has the correct syntax. I would question the table parameter, and also how you're passing the user id into the string.